# How to populate a cell with information stored in a location relative to the value in another cell?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Let's say I have

```
Sheet 1
   A   B   C  
1  #   20  30
2  #   75  90
3  #   46  21

Sheet 2
   A   B   C  
1  X       Y
```

Where "X" is a dropdown list of Sheet 1's B column.

"Y" is where I want to fill in the value in the C column of the respective row of Sheet 1 for Sheet 2's column A selection.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1; 'Sheet 1'!B:C; 2; 0)
```

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1; 'Sheet 1'!B:C; 2; 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In C1 try

```
=IF(LEN(A1), VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1!B:C, 2, 0),)
```